# accessing a ui.label from main.cpp in QT

Tags: qt

i am trying to take a feedback data which is published from arduino and subscribed to my GUI created in QT.

Now i have main.cpp and mainwindow.cpp.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include "../include/abc/main_window.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::UInt16 &fb_msg){
    ROS_INFO("Feedback: [%f]", fb_msg.data);
    ui.label_6->setText(QString("%1").arg(fb_msg.data));
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("feedback",1000, chatterCallback);
ros::spinOnce();
QApplication app(argc, argv);
abc::MainWindow w(argc,argv);
w.show();
w.setWindowTitle("GUI for Controlling Servo Motor");
app.connect(&app, SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
int result = app.exec();
return result;}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
namespace abc {

using namespace Qt;
QSerialPort *serial;

MainWindow::MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, qnode(argc,argv)
{
ui.setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
void MainWindow::on_horizontalSlider_valueChanged(int value)
{
ui.label_5->setText(QString("%1").arg(value));
msg.data = ui.label_5->text().toUInt();
ROS_INFO("%d", msg.data);
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
ros::spinOnce();
}
```

main_window.hpp

```
#ifndef abc_MAIN_WINDOW_H
#define abc_MAIN_WINDOW_H
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_main_window.h"
#include "qnode.hpp"
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "std_msgs/UInt16.h"

namespace abc {

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT

public:
MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

public Q_SLOTS:

private:

Ui::MainWindowDesign ui;
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise <std_msgs::UInt16> ("chatter", 1000);
QSerialPort *arduino;
QNode qnode;
};

}  // namespace abc

#endif // abc_MAIN_WINDOW_H
```

Now when i run this code, it shows me that UI is not declared in main.cpp.

I wanted to display the data from feedback to label_6 (TextBox). The data is only available in main.cpp, any suggestions are highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question: 1. From where are getting this feedback values? 2. I am guessing the UI has a label_6 that can be accessed from mainWindow.cpp just like you accessed label_5, is that right?

Comment: The feedback is taken from Arduino, which is accurately received.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the `fb_msg.data` as an argument to the `MainWindow` constructor. Then you can set the UI element in the `MainWindow` thread.
Alternatively once you create the `MainWindow` instance in your main, you can emit a signal which you catch and process in the `MainWindow` thread.

You cannot modify the UI elements from a different thread.